# Ruby On Rails Integrate Apache Solr to search files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, sunspot-rails

I need my ROR app to search files like pdf, xml, doc, xls etc...

I'm using apache solr to do this.I'm sending query string to the solr url and able to retrieve the details in json format and display the file names in my app views.

I need to make the file names clickable so as to open those files.I don't know how to make this.Any help will be great.Is there any option in apache solr to open those files or any gem supports this.

In apache solr app screens also I,m not able to open files.I don't know whether there is any option in apache solr.This may sound quite silly, but I'm new to Apache solr and don't have much idea about the working of solr.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about document searching. If you use sunspot solr gem there is an add-on which is used for document searching. Have a look at this: [sunspot_cell](https://github.com/chebyte/sunspot_cell)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Currently I'm able to search files but I want to make those file names clickable so as, I should be able to open that file.This option I didn't see in any of the gems.